# Executing commands using DbCommand in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, oracle

ok I used the DbClass so I could use both Oracle and sql without having to have 2 different dills, I just pass the connection and the provider and that's it.
This is how I am opening the connection:

```
public class CdpsiUpdateSql : IDisposable
{        
    private DbTransaction _myTransaction;
    bool disposed = false;
    SafeHandle handle = new SafeFileHandle(IntPtr.Zero, true);
    public DbConnection OraConnection { get; set; }

    public CdpsiUpdateSql(string Provider, string connectionString)
    {
        //this.OraConnection = OpenDbConnection(connectionString);
        string constr = connectionString;

            DbProviderFactory factory =
                    DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(Provider);
        DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = constr;
        conn.Open();
        this.OraConnection = conn;

    }
```

but now I need to execute several commands using that connection (OraConnection), I have another DLL that executes the commands, and I have this function:

```
private bool ExecComando(string comando, CdpsiUpdateSql Updater, string log)
{
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
    string sql = comando;
    DbCommand cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand(sql);
    cmd.Connection = Updater.OraConnection;
    try
    {
        linhas = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return false;
    }
    catch (DbException exp)
    {
        Logg("Erro a executar o comando: " + comando, log);
        Logg("Descrição do erro: " + exp.ToString(), log);
        cmd.Dispose();
        return true;
    }
}
```

> it throws an exception asking to set a DatabaseProviderFactory which needs a config file.
>   I can't found anything conclusive on this, because info is really scarse when it comes to this class.
>   If it's any relevant when testing I used the provider >"Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" and the connection using the first method works just fine, it connects successfully.
>   What do I need to use to execute the commands?
>   Any help is appreciated, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `DatabaseFactory` class at all, in my opinion.

I think you can use the `CreateCommand` method of the `DbConnection` class. Something like:

```
var cmd = Updater.OraConnection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = sql;
...
```

I think it's even better to declare the connection with a private setter.

```
public DbConnection OraConnection { get; private set; }
```

Much more elegant and safe.